# tweepy.binder module not found

Tags: python, tweepy

After successly installing requirements there a module that isn't found, I think it's a problem with the `bind9` module because there isn't a module named `tweepy.binder`. buts the result are same.

logs:

> Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Pillow-9.2.0 PyYAML-6.0 Werkzeug-2.2.2 certifi-2022.9.14 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 click-8.1.3 flask-2.2.2 httplib2-0.20.4 idna-3.4 importlib-metadata-4.12.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2 oauth2-1.9.0.post1 oauthlib-3.2.1 pyngrok-5.1.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 requests-2.28.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 tweepy-4.10.1 urllib3-1.26.12 waitress-2.1.2 zipp-3.8.1

```
(venv) bot@lnxbot-1:~/botmaster$ python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/bot/botmaster/app.py", line 4, in from twitter_autobase import Autobase
 File "/home/bot/botmaster/twitter_autobase/init.py", line 11, in from .main import Autobase
 File "/home/bot/botmaster/twitter_autobase/main.py", line 9, in from .twitter import Twitter
 File "/home/bot/botmaster/twitter_autobase/twitter.py", line 13, in from tweepy.binder import bind_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy.binder' 

(venv) bot@lnxbot-1:~/botmaster$ sudo apt install bind9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
bind9 is already the newest version (1:9.16.27-1~deb11u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

so what is wrong? thanks!

Comment: I don't know the technology you're using, but the connection between `bind9` and `tweepy.binder` is really not clear from the logs you shared.

Comment: But when I look at the documentation for the latest version of tweepy, there is no module called `tweepy.binder` anymore. I can only find references to that module in a 9 year-old repo. I suspect your app was written against an older version of tweepy, maybe 3.0? You might have to install that version instead of 4.10.1 as you did.

Comment: But then you're likely to encounter all sorts of other incompatibilities, so brace yourself for lots of debugging! Or ask the app developers if they have a more recent version, compatible with current library versions.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `binder.py` was removed with version 4.0.0, so you might be able to use 3.10.0, which was released in 2020, so all hope might not be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.py` code is importing from `tweepy.binder`, but that module was removed with version 4.0.0 of `tweepy`.

See the [changelog](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/changelog.md) for version 4.0.0:

> Replace `bind_api` and `APIMethod` with `API.request`

Your best short-term option is to install version 3.10.0 of tweepy, the last one that provided `tweepy.binder.bind_api` like your app expects. Ideally change your `requirements.txt` file to specify that version, or else install it manually:

```
python3 -m pip install tweepy==3.10.0
```

Your best long-term option is to adapt the code to use the latest version of the `tweepy` library.